# Do I need to define properties in a PHP class?

Tags: php

Do you need to define variables as properties if you set them in the constructor? Is there a difference between these two?

```
class Foo1
{
  function __construct($bar)
  {
    $this->bar = $bar;
  }
}

class Foo2
{
  public $bar; // <-- The above works, so do I need this?

  function __construct($bar)
  {
    $this->bar = $bar;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are dealing with `classes`, you probably want encapsulation, and so PHP gives you the tools to achieve it, by specifying the visibility on the top.
For public it does not make such big difference, but for example

```
class ...{
    private $some_private_key;
}
```

you can only achieve it using the `private` keyword at the top, you can't achieve this in the constructor like in your first example.

Note: also specifying `public ...` at the top makes a big difference if you are dealing with classes that has magic method like `__get` and `__set`, because the resolution of that field will access the property declared on the top, and won't invoke those magic method